# Microservices Deployment Manager

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment, microservices

I was wondering how information on deployed applications are kept in real, production environments (yeah, I am a novice) . For example, in a microservices based set up, if  5 microservices-based  applications were deployed in production environments. Let's say each of those had 4 - 6 instances each, are there special software for keeping record of these applications? I know the records can be easily written into a database but I can imagine some better solutions out there.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Cloud Native Landscape](https://landscape.cncf.io/images/landscape.png), you are looking for a `Coordination & Service Discovery`:

[image]

https://etcd.io/

> A distributed, reliable key-value store for the most critical data of
>   a distributed system

https://github.com/Netflix/eureka

> Eureka is a REST (Representational State Transfer) based service that
>   is primarily used in the AWS cloud for locating services for the
>   purpose of load balancing and failover of middle-tier servers.

https://github.com/alibaba/nacos

> Nacos (official site: http://nacos.io) is an easy-to-use platform
>   designed for dynamic service discovery and configuration and service
>   management. It helps you to build cloud native applications and
>   microservices platform easily.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. However, my experience with `registry and service discovery` e.g. Netflix Eureka, falls short of my requirements.  There are two major reasons, first, the systems you listed retain information ephemerally i.e. all information is lost following a shutdown. Secondly, asides the application metadata e.g. endpoints, it is important to have knowledge about deployment dates, test dates i.e. the information about the application's lifecycle. Therefore, I was hoping for a solution that aggregates all these disjointed pieces of information.

Comment: Maybe Helm could fill the role of providing the deployment dates and other lifecycle things?

Comment: @theOther can you briefly explain? I am not conversant with helm, a quick look at the documentation (https://helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#quickstart) gives me no clues.